# Organiser application in Qt

Tags: qt

I need to write a project in Qt that will show a calendar in which day-cells are buttons that allow you to see and add some tasks you have to do. Because I am kind of new to Qt and don't have much time to complete this task I was wondering if anyone could tell me which libraries should I use. Will QtCalendarWidget be a good choice? Does it have a possibility to make cells react like separate buttons? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QtCalendarWidget` is good choice that fits your needs.
This widget has signal:

```
void QCalendarWidget::clicked ( const QDate & date ) [signal]
```

Which you can link to what you want, as you do it in Qt.

Read more at [official documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcalendarwidget.html)